# Unable to locate object referenced in object method without redundant import

Tags: python, jinja2

I was attempting to render a Jinja2 template while passing in a single parameter. This parameter is an instance of an object which has a method that references a second object. The object I'm passing into Jinja2 is stored in one module, while the referenced object is stored in a second module. The rendering takes place in a third module. The original code would error out when the first object's method references the second object (`global name ... is not defined`). This method works fine outside of Jinja2. Here's a simple example to set the scene...

The jinja2 rendering module looks like this:

```
from jinja2 import Template
from module1 import *
from module2 import *

def return_rendered():
    otr = ObjectToRender()
    otr.name = 'Just making the instance special!'

    temp_str = open('template.html', 'r')
    template = Template(temp_str.read())
    temp_str.close()

    return template.render(otr=otr)
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<p>Here is the output from a super cool method!<p>
{{ otr.get_a_cool_name() }}
```

The object to render:

```
# module1
class ObjectToRender(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    def get_a_cool_name(self):
        rc = ReferencedClass() # fails here with "global name 
                               # 'ReferencedClass' is not defined"
        return rc.make_cool(self.name)

from module2 import *
```

and the referenced class:

```
# module2
from module1 import *
class ReferencedClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cool_str = 'SUPER COOL'

    def make_cool(self, in_str):
        return in_str + self.cool_str
```

You'll notice I've imported modules 1 and 2 "into each other". It's obviously not necessary here, but in my use case it is. Anyway, I was able to get this working by importing the second class again, just before the `ReferencedClass` is used. It looks like this:

```
# module1
class ObjectToRender(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    def get_a_cool_name(self):
        from module2 import ReferencedClass
        rc = ReferencedClass() # it works! 
        return rc.make_cool(self.name)

from module2 import *
```

So, I got it working without really understanding why it didn't work in the first place... Classic. Does anyone know why I'm having to import this class a second time?

Comment: `You'll notice I've imported modules 1 and 2 "into each other".` - yeah, don't do that. Pretty much never do that.

Comment: Module1 contains my SQLAlchemy ORM and Module2 contains a collection of classes. Some classes need to access the database, and some SQLAlchemy objects take advantage of the classes created in Module1. Dual import can obviously complicate some things... @user2357112, any suggestions? I would be stoked to get a good one